# Update component when prop value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object with the property `home.ready = false`. When the object is done getting data, cleaning it etc it changes to `home.ready= true`.

I need my component to register the change and update. My component:

```
 class HomeNav extends React.Component {
      render() {
          let data = this.props.data;
          let uniqueTabs = _.uniq(_.map(data, x => x.tab)).sort();

          let tabs = uniqueTabs.map((tab, index) => {
              let itemsByTab = _.filter(data, (x => x.tab == tab));
              return <Tabs key={tab} tab={tab} index={index} data={itemsByTab} />;
          });
          console.log(this.props)
          return (
              <section>
                  <div className="wb-tabs">
                      <div className="tabpanels">
                        { this.props.ready ? {tabs} : <p>Loading...</p> }
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
          )
      }
  };

ReactDOM.render(
  <HomeNav data={home.data.nav} ready={home.ready}/>,
  document.getElementById('home-nav')
);
```

This is the [home object](https://github.com/simkessy/sharepoint-projects/blob/master/dynamic-home/dynamic-home.js). It's a simple object that gets data and once the data is ready the property `ready` changes from `false` to `true`. I can't get React to recognize that change. And at times React will say `home` is undefined.

Comment: Not sure what you want. If you pass `ready` as a prop to your component it should update automatically if its value changed. It should be your container component that gets the data and set the `home.ready` which then passes it down to `HomeNav`.

Comment: There is nothing in this code sample called `home`. Include the code that passes the `prop`!

Comment: @this-vidor `home` is an object in another script. The default value of home.ready is `false` and when my data is retrieved it's changed to `true`. This is the home object is you want to see it: https://github.com/simkessy/sharepoint-projects/blob/master/dynamic-home/dynamic-home.js

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post any code around the request, or data formatting, I will assume you got all that figured out. So, for your component to work the way it is currently written, you need to drop the curly braces around `tabs` (`{ this.props.ready ? tabs : <p>Loading...</p> }`), then, `this.props.data` should always contain a valid Array, otherwise it will break when you try to sort, filter, etc.

---

**Or**, you can do an early dropout, based on the `ready` property:

```
class HomeNav extends React.Component {
      render() {
          if(!this.props.ready){
              return <section>
                  <div className="wb-tabs">
                      <div className="tabpanels">
                          <p>Loading...</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
          }

          let data = this.props.data;
          let uniqueTabs = _.uniq(_.map(data, x => x.tab)).sort();

          let tabs = uniqueTabs.map((tab, index) => {
              let itemsByTab = _.filter(data, (x => x.tab == tab));
              return <Tabs key={tab} tab={tab} index={index} data={itemsByTab} />;
          });
          console.log(this.props)
          return (
              <section>
                  <div className="wb-tabs">
                      <div className="tabpanels">
                        {tabs}
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </section>
          )
      }
  };
```

Comment: The request and data formatting happens outside of React. I'm using a object to retrieve and parse the data. So I have to work around making sure that React waits for that object to be ready and being able to determine when changes have been made, like `home.ready`

Comment: @Batman: Sorry, I didn't get your point. I understand what you are saying, that is actually a pretty common case, I just can't see what you are having problems with. Could you please clarify?